# Fire a jQuery event when element gets pushed to new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I fire a jquery event if the element in view gets pushed to a new line?  I'd like to hide the nav items and also run some other javascript when this happens. Any suggestions on how to do this?

In a large view this is what my nav looks like:

[image: Large view nav]

This is what happens when I reduce my screen width.  When this happens I want to fire events on those elements.  How do I do this?

[image: Shorter width navigation]

Comment: how about check the width of the div inside the jquery .resize event?

Comment: I could do that be then I have to set specific width sizes to run my JavaScript. It would work, but just doesn't seem to be as ideal to have to map out every size.  If I change the name of a tab then all the sizes will get screwed up.  Any alternatives?

Comment: How about a collapsible nav. bar? In that case you need to only map one size. This would work even if you change the tab name. An example with twitter bootstrap: http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/navbar-example

Answer (score 0):

If the view get's pushed down, it's based on the width of the container.

Try using  [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) to keep track of the width & call the relevant functions when the width get's lower.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  // if the navigation DIV's width is smaller than xyz, do this ...

});
```

Comment: See my comment above.